# are "displayed upfront" and "hidden covertly" the same? I guess not and I need a double check

Tags: phrase-meaning, redundancy, antonyms

This [post](https://www.drumbeatmarketing.net/marketing-blog/4-easiest-ways-tell-image-copyrighted) says

> overlays of a symbol or text that may be hidden covertly or displayed
>   upfront to protect an image from being used without owner’s approval.

to illustrate above, the post gives this picture.

[image: picture with a watermark]

are "displayed upfront" and "hidden covertly" the same? I guess not, because

[covertly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/covertly) means “not openly shown” according to Merriam-Webster.

so, this picture illustrates only part of that description (displayed upfront), is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are different.

The illustration is of a watermark "displayed upfront" — clearly and openly, you see it before you do anything with  the image. It's designed to make it difficult to use the image.

There is also a method of watermarking which is a form of [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography): the tracking data is hidden within the image itself, generally by altering specific bits of the data in a defined method. In this case, it's not upfront at all; it's covert. The image doesn't generally **look** any different, and it's easy to re-use it; but the watermark allows the image's owner to prove a copied image's origin.